# Abstract with light background color

Tags: color, backgrounds, abstract, amsart

Is there a way to add a background color to the abstract? I tried various combinations of `\colorbox` and the `\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}` environment, but nothing worked.

I use the current TexShop version with default setting. Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[size=normalsize,format=plain,textfont=sc]{caption}

\bibstyle{alpha}
\geometry{a4paper}                      

\title{some title}
\author{the author}
\date{} % delete this line to display the current date

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 

\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\twocolumn
\input{1}

\input{2}

\input{3}

\input{4}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Lit}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). One option would be to use `\usepackage{xcolor,mdframed}`, and wrap the abstract in `\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=yellow!10]`, \end{mdframed}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill this will not work with `amsart` due to the way it handles the abstract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the standard `article` class it would suffice to wrap the `abstract` environment inside some appropriate element (a `\colorbox`, for example); however, since you are using `amsart`, additional work is required: you need to redefine the `abstract` environment to use, for example, a `mdframed` environment (from the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package) with the desired background color; a little example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                   
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

\geometry{a4paper}                      

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \ifx\maketitle\relax
    \ClassWarning{\@classname}{Abstract should precede
      \protect\maketitle\space in AMS documentclasses; reported}%
  \fi
  \global\setbox\abstractbox=\vtop \bgroup
    \normalfont\Small
    \list{}{\labelwidth\z@
      \leftmargin3pc \rightmargin\leftmargin
      \listparindent\normalparindent \itemindent\z@
      \parsep\z@ \@plus\p@
      \let\fullwidthdisplay\relax
    }%
    \item[]\vskip-\baselineskip
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20,hidealllines=true]
    \item[\hskip\labelsep\scshape\abstractname.]%
}{%
  \end{mdframed}\endlist\egroup
  \ifx\@setabstract\relax \@setabstracta \fi
}
\makeatother

\title{some title}
\author{the author}
\date{} % delete this line to display the current date

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[4]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

On a side note, the `abstract` environment must be placed *before* `\maketitle` when using `amsart`.

Here's another option using the `framed` package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                   
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

\geometry{a4paper}                      

\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!20}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \ifx\maketitle\relax
    \ClassWarning{\@classname}{Abstract should precede
      \protect\maketitle\space in AMS documentclasses; reported}%
  \fi
  \global\setbox\abstractbox=\vtop \bgroup\begin{shaded}
    \normalfont\Small
    \list{}{\labelwidth\z@
      \leftmargin3pc \rightmargin\leftmargin
      \listparindent\normalparindent \itemindent\z@
      \parsep\z@ \@plus\p@
      \let\fullwidthdisplay\relax
    }%
   \item[\hskip\labelsep\scshape\abstractname.]%
}{%

\endlist\end{shaded}\egroup
  \ifx\@setabstract\relax \@setabstracta \fi
}
\makeatother

\title{some title}
\author{the author}
\date{} % delete this line to display the current date

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[4]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!
Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it, neither with my file nor when I copy/paste your example file and try to run it.
In either case, I receive the following error message:

`./test.tex:38: Package keyval Error: hidealllines undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.38 \begin{abstract}
                     
?`

Comment: @tgraf the error indicates that you have an outdated version of the mdframed package; you can update your LaTeX installation. In the meantime I provided another solution using this time the framed package.

Comment: As it turned out, I had an outdated version of a zillion of packages.

Working like a charm now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you want the color box the same width as the text then put it into a minipage

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\Abstract\abstract
\long\def\abstract{\mdframed[backgroundcolor=blue!20,hidealllines=true]
  \vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}\Abstract}
\let\endAbstract\endabstract
\def\endabstract{\endAbstract\endmdframed\par\bigskip}

\title{some title}
\author{the author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[4]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]